# Runnable jar cannot find resources?

Tags: java

I have an application that runs fine in eclipse (a pdf generator using `jasper reports`).
The app requires a font which is placed into `src/main/resources/fonts`.

Now I export the app as executable jar. There is a folder `resources/fonts/` in the jar correctly.

Anyhow: when I run `java -jar app.jar` I'm getting an exception that the resource is not found:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font :
pdfFontName   : Arial
pdfEncoding   : Cp1252
isPdfEmbedded : true
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getFont(JRPdfExporter.java:2152)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getChunk(JRPdfExporter.java:1942)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getPhrase(JRPdfExporter.java:1911)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.SimplePdfTextRenderer.getPhrase(SimplePdfTextRenderer.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.SimplePdfTextRenderer.render(SimplePdfTextRenderer.java:98)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportText(JRPdfExporter.java:2275)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:985)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportFrame(JRPdfExporter.java:2779)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:989)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:944)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:816)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:519)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdf(JasperExportManager.java:218)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(JasperExportManager.java:543)
```

Neglecting jasperreports: what can be cases where the jar does not find contained resources?

Comment: Ignoring the reports things that are on the top of my head are: 1)resource linking done badly, how did you link the file in your code? maybe it's using a specific local path that falls out of scope once you run the code outside of eclipe?
2)Add it as a library?

Answer (score 0):

The font should not be in `resources/fonts/` but in `fonts/` in your jar file.